# Value Conversion Issue error on app build

Tags: ios, xcode, libyaml

I am trying to test my app in Xcode but every time I try to build it I get several Value Conversion Issues.  The developer I worked with was able to open and work with the file without any issues.  I get 8 errors  in my libYAML files that say the following:

Value Conversion Issue
Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int'

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you building on the 64-bit simulator, but your developer is building on the regular one?

Comment: hmmm I'm not sure, but I did notice that as I switch between simulators the number of errors goes from 3 to 8...

Comment: Yeah, so you have some warnings that will only appears on a 64-bit CPU.  Read "Changes to Data Types" on https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

That means you're assigning a long to an int, since long can store larger values than int, it might not fit into it.
Why don't you change your int to long?

Comment: can you copy/paste here the lines with the warnings?